# phpMyAdmin dynamic sql - how to use?

Tags: sql, dynamic, phpmyadmin, exec, sp-executesql

Does dynamic SQL work in phpMyAdmin?

I tried the most basic examples from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiAwOoelu9k

For instance, each of these throws an error (tried separately):
EXEC ('SELECT data FROM table')
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT data FROM table'

Comment: phpmyadmin is a tool to handle mysql. That video refers to sql server. Executing those commands in phpmyadmin will certainly not work. What is it that you really want to do?

Comment: I need to access data in sub-site tables of a WP multisite set-up, and put the selected data into a VIEW in a separate database.  (Both the WP database and the separate databases are on the same server.)    The SQL statement for the VIEW currently obtains the blog_id from the blogs table in the WP multisite database.  But to use the blog_id to obtain data from the corresponding sub-site, I need to  concatenate the blog_id within the SQL statement. (The blog_id is included in all of the sub-site table names.)

Comment: That is a big change in question. Did you manage to understand what you were doing wrong regarding to this question? As for your last comment, you should probably write a new question with that. Don't forget to add details regarding the table schemas, sample data and the tools you are using. It always helps on getting good answers

Comment: Hi Filipe - thank you for your replies.  I think there is a miss - the details I provided are for context only.  The original question is what I need the answer to, not the broader objective.  I am researching and will post the answer here if I find it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in multiple Stackoverflow streams (listed below).  It depends on the version of phpMyAdmin, which needs to be v3.5.2.2 or higher.  This is because Dyanamic SQL is part of a STORED PROCEDURE.  Older versions of phpMyAdmin allow you to CREATE a STORED PROCEDURE, but the ability to CALL a STORED PROCEDURE within phpMyAdmin requires version 3.5.2.2 or higher.  (Source: [is it possible to run a stored procedure from within phpmyadmin 3.4.10.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875864/is-it-possible-to-run-a-stored-procedure-from-within-phpmyadmin-3-4-10-1))

For those using an older version of phpMyAdmin who need to use Dynamic SQL, an alternative is Workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

For those using phpMyAdmin version 3.5.2.2 or higher, to CREATE and CALL a STORED PROCEDURE, here are posts of other users:

How to write a stored procedure using phpmyadmin and how to use it through php? [How to write a stored procedure using phpmyadmin and how to use it through php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846516/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-using-phpmyadmin-and-how-to-use-it-through-php)

MySQL procedure not getting created/working using phpmyadmin [mysql procedure not getting created/working using phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654538/mysql-procedure-not-getting-created-working-using-phpmyadmin)

How do I view my stored procedures in phpMyAdmin? [How do I view my stored procedures in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115573/how-do-i-view-my-stored-procedures-in-phpmyadmin)

I created several stored procedures in phpmyadmin, how to call them using an sql query? [I created several stored procedures in phpmyadmin, how to call them using an sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490537/i-created-several-stored-procedures-in-phpmyadmin-how-to-call-them-using-an-sql)